# What should I focus my guitar practice on?

Tags: guitar, practice

As an aspiring guitarist, I would like to have some direction as to what my goals should be. Right now I've been playing guitar for a little over 8 months, and have around 500 hours under my belt.
I've mostly been learning things sporadically that pique my interest. Accordingly, I can play open chords, power chords, barre chords, and a handful of jazz and pop chords. As far as scales go, I know the Major, Minor, Harmonic Minor, Melodic Minor, Dorian, and Sakura scales. My phrasing when improvising is alright, but I'm not sure what to focus on for practice. At the moment the only songs I know how to play are "Sweet Home Alabama" and "Just The Two of Us"

Three months ago I started vastly improving my technique for fear of carpal tunnel, and about a month and a half ago I got frustrated with how I locked myself into one particular style every time I play and started adding tapping and hybrid picking into my playing.

(I don't know how to read sheet music)

My point is that I don't have any goals in mind other than getting better at guitar, but I have no milestones to judge my progress on, nor do I completely understand what it means to become "good" at guitar. What are some basic goals I can have to keep my practice consistent and gratifying? I would like guitar to be more of a skill than an escape.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the core question is "what goals should I have?", and that's a question only you can answer. Anything this site can offer would be sheer opinion, which is "off topic". However, you might find a very fruitful discussion in the site's chat room.

Comment: If you want to set some goals for yourself, books, sheet music, recordings, and live concerts may give you inspiration.  Technically, the challenge is to play more challenging material without sacrificing the technical strides you have made (avoiding unnecessary tension).  You might enjoy working with some play-along recordings that give you the backing track to improvise off of.  Learning to conduct, and read music (and eventually scores), and sight sing and sight read on your instrument, can be helpful supplemental activities.  Ensembles can be fun, inspiring and rewarding.  Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

OK so first you need some "Guitar Heroes" you know that people who both inspires and humiliates you. It really depends on what kind of music do you listen to and the style you want to achive. Are you a metal, rock, country, bluessy, jazz head, classical, flamenco, gypsy or folk player?

If you don´t know where to start I´ll recomend: Jason Becker, Marty Friedman, David Guilmour, Jeff Beck, Stevie Ray Vaughan, Chet Atkins, Guthrie Govan, BB king, Wes Montgomery, Joe Pass, Francisco Tarrega, Heitor Villalobos, Paco de Lucia, Django Reindhardt, Santana.

Now the next question is "Do I want to make my own music?" if the answer is yes, then you should start learning functional harmony, tonalities, the circle of fifths, pentatonic patterns, how to count rythm and that´s all you need.

More important is to find people to play along with, maybe you don´t feel as confident of your skills but neither they, so why not to improve while having a good time sharing your passion for music. Usually you play with your friends but if that´s not the case, then you surely find someone eager if you know where to search.

Being in a band would motivate you to keep going and focus on learning something new, and also it shows you how hard is to keep on time if the drummer is off (even if you learn the song properly).

Do you grab correctly your pick? that could be the reason why you suffer when playing, it should be as comfortable as writing. You don´t really need to learn scales if you really undertand intervals and how they work respect to a chord, playing leads is all about the chord you are playing over.

If you really want yourself to be called a musician, please learn how to tune by ear and practice trying to emulate melodies also by ear once you know how to figure out a key signature, they don´t have to be guitar melodies or riffs, just some catchy melody you heard from a pop song, they are both easy and great for developing a melodic sense.

About techniches: tapping is easy, the hard part is making it sound not like a bunch of random notes. Alternate picking is the way to achieve speed and accuracy, and it can be tough at high speed. Tremolo picking is when you realize there´s a way to play as fast as shit without having your hand falling off, that´s also the time where you finally start to know how the right hand works. Hybrid picking it´s hard no idea why you said you can. Bends and vibrato... finally you started to feel the music and not just rush like a dumbass. Arpeggios, it´s time to get this shit serious. Sweep picking don´t even dream about this, it just wont happend until the fifth year of practice, and it will be completely sloppy.

Last advice: listen to a lot of music, not only the things you already like, but those you don´t really know much about it. Talk with people about the music you like, believe it or not you can find something interesting even if you thought you knew alredy everything.

Comment: As far as the good advice from this, thank you. But I especially want to thank you for telling me what I can't do. Now I have the motivation to learn sweep picking and get my hybrid picking down to a T (It's not much harder than fingerpicking, I just need to use my pinky more)

Comment: one thing I found useful as far as working out songs I like is: have three goals. One that you think can be achieved tomorrow, one that will take months, and one that will take years. So a simpler catchy thing, something complex, and then Jimi Hendrix or Mahavishnu Orchestra circa 1972. You will always have something to noodle on that builds on prior experience and is "more funner" than running scales.

Comment: @Yorik So would Playing God by Polyphia be a good goal that will take years? I just printed out the tabs